# Angular Translate a number in ngx-translate in i18n

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to translate a number in i18n json file

```
"category":[{"1":"home"},{"2":"search"},{"3":"account"}]
```

and for *ngFor

```
<div *ngFor="let post of posts">
    {{ post.category | translate }}
</div>
```

but the number is cannot translate to its value
the category value return a number 1,2,3
I need to translate this result to a value from the json file

Comment: please include the entire relevant part of your template

Comment: @Rafi Henig I updated the code

Comment: It seems that currently `post.category` is an array. Are you sure the example is correct?

Comment: Try this: 

    <div *ngFor="let post of posts">
        <span i18n>{{post.category}}</span>
    </div

Comment: @Łukasz Nojek I can edit the "category" in the i18n json file to get the correct value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following approach:

```
"category":{
  "1":"home",
  "2":"search",
  "3":"account"
 }
```

Template:

```html
<div *ngFor="let post of posts">
  {{ "category." + post.category | translate}}
</div>
```